# Twitter API search user's tweets between dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

Is there a way to get tweets for a certain user between dates? I tried using Search API, but no success. The user's timeline api does not have date parameters.

The only way that I found is get the 200 most recent tweets of the user and check by parsing date.

```
$.getJSON(
                'http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/' + account_name + '.json?callback=?',
                function(data){
                    if (!data || data.length === 0)
                        return false;

                    var date = new Date(data[0].created_at);
                    //[Date comparison goes here]

                }
            );
```

I think there is a better way to to this, but searching not helped at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The search API supports this, but you have to assemble your query like so:

http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=+from%3Atwitterapi+since%3A2011-06-20+until%3A2011-06-20

The query string above is the urlencoded form of:

```
q= from:twitterapi since:2011-06-20 until:2011-06-20
```

The list of search operators can be found [here](http://search.twitter.com/operators).

Comment: Worth noting that there are only limited tweets available when using the search API (See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/things-every-developer-should-know)

Comment: What about the same task in 1.1 ? How to convert date to since id ?

Comment: @Bobby_D_ the best you can do is pass **since_id** and **max_id** in something like the [user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline) api. Only really useful if you happen to know the ids of two tweets bracketing the timeline you're interested in. Building a business around social media apis sucks.

Comment: Search API index has a 7 day limit: until optional

Returns tweets created before the given date. Date should be formatted as YYYY-MM-DD. Keep in mind that the search index has a 7-day limit. In other words, no tweets will be found for a date older than one week.

Example Values: 2015-07-19